# Problem to connect the django with mongodb using djongo

Tags: python, django, djongo

**How i use**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'rede_social',
        'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://blackwolf449:3CErLxvGLPM4rLsK@cluster0.w1ucl2e.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USER': 'blackwolf449',
        'PASSWORD': '3CErLxvGLPM4rLsK'
    }
}
```

**Error**

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
> 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Comment: Did you `pip install djongo`?

Comment: And change your password asap.

Comment: yes i did, i try everything

Comment: How do you run the django app? Are you using a virtual environment? Double check that the packages are installed in the same environment that you use to run the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by installing Pytz.
Do :

> pip install pytz

Answer (score 0):

downgrade your django version to 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

The configuration should look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'your-db-name',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'host-name or ip address',
                'port': port_number,
                'username': 'db-username',
                'password': 'password',
                'authSource': 'db-name',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
            },
            'LOGGING': {
                'version': 1,
                'loggers': {
                    'djongo': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'propagate': False,                        
                    }
                },
             },
        }
    }
```

See djongo docs: https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/